# payload.member returns none on on_raw_reaction_remove() but works with on_raw_reaction_add()

Tags: discord.py

so im making a discord bot and I have an error:

> Ignoring exception in on_raw_reaction_remove
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
> await coro(*args, **kwargs)
> File "main.py", line 41, in on_raw_reaction_remove
> await payload.member.remove_roles(role)
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'remove_roles'

on_raw_reaction_remove() code:

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):
  if payload.message_id == 865402961585111111:
    if str(payload.emoji) == "✅":
      guild = client.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
      role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Announcements')
      await payload.member.remove_roles(role)
```

on_raw_reaction_add() code:

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
  if payload.message_id == 865402961585111111:
    if str(payload.emoji) == "✅":
      guild = client.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
      role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Announcements')
      await payload.member.add_roles(role)
```

The strange thing is, with on_raw_reaction_add() it returns a valid user.

Comment: `NoneType` = Something does not exist.

Comment: I know, that's the problem.  payload.member returns none type even though it should return a member

Comment: Try `payload.member.guild.roles` instead.

Comment: but that's not the issue, the issue is that payload.member is none, and when I did what you said it told me "none does not have attribute guild"

Comment: Do you have Intents enabled?

Comment: yeah, as I said it works for on_raw_reaction_add()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your event a bit and added some checks to make sure everything is correct.

There were always problems with finding the role, so you need to do things a little differently.

**Take a look at the following code:**

```py
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):
    guild = client.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
    print("Guild checked.")
    member = discord.utils.get(guild.members, id=payload.user_id)
    print("Member checked.")
    if payload.message_id == 865402961585111111:
        print("Got message.")
        if str(payload.emoji) == "✅":
            print("Checked for the reaction.")
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Announcements')
            print("Got the role.")
        else:
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=payload.emoji)

        if role is not None:
            await member.remove_roles(role)
            print("Removed the role")
```

If the code is not self-explanatory, I'll be happy to add some explanations.

**EDIT:**
After looking at the full code the problem seems to be with the Intents. You named them correctly but did not import them.

**To import them you use:**

```py
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="YourPrefix", intents=intents1)
```

Comment: the member var equals none type for me

Comment: @koiyaboi What are you doing then? The code works perfectly fine for me. Then the bot is not able to get the member or something similar.

Comment: but the bot got the member for on_raw_reaction_add()

Comment: Can you please edit your post and show the other code also?

Comment: @koiyaboi So in which line do the print statements stop?

Comment: it stops at "got the role" with the error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'remove_roles'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234986/discussion-between-dominik-and-koiyaboi).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but apparently, in "on_raw_reaction_remove" it doesn't work to do payload.member, instead of this, you should do the following:

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):
  if payload.message_id == 865402961585111111:
  guild = client.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
  member = discord.utils.get(guild.members, id=payload.user_id)
    if str(payload.emoji) == "✅":
      role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Announcements')
      await member.remove_roles(role)
```

I hope I've helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the member object in on_raw_reaction_remove by converting the user_id to a member object like this:

```py
guild_id = payload.guild_id
guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g : g.id == guild_id, client.guilds)
member = await guild.fetch_member(payload.user_id)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).